# initial= not working on Form inputs

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a simple search form on my page `/`.

```
class SearchForm(Form):
    query = CharField(max_length=256,
                      label="Search",
                      required=False,
                      widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Search …',
                                              'class': 'form-control'}))

    page = IntegerField(min_value=8, initial=1, widget=HiddenInput())
    sort = CharField(max_length=16, initial="id", widget=HiddenInput())
    order = CharField(max_length=4, initial="asc", widget=HiddenInput())
```

My (simplified) view is this:

```
def search(request):
    search_form = SearchForm(request.GET)        
    return render(request, "search.html", {'search_form': search_form})
```

My goal is to have `search_form.cleaned_data['<FIELD>']` return the initial values I set in the class `SearchForm`, without having to check wether they are exist `None` or are empty `''`.

Unfortunately my code does not work as the input elements are renderd like this:

```
<input id="id_page" name="page" type="hidden" />
<input id="id_sort" maxlength="16" name="sort" type="hidden" />
<input id="id_order" maxlength="4" name="order" type="hidden" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: in this case, you probably want to use default rather than initial

Comment: `default` is not a valid argument in this context.

Comment: sorry got confused with model - but you should pass initial value during form instantion

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason the code would not work was because

```
search_form = SearchForm(request.GET)
```

creates a bound form. And bound forms don't have initial values.

I ended up with this gem. It checks if `request.GET` contains at least one of the form's fields (regardless of value, e. g. `/?page=`) and then creates a bound form where validation can happen. Otherwise the user visited `/` or submitted other parameters not related to the form (e. g. `/?foo=bar`).

```
if request.GET & SearchForm.base_fields.keys():
    search_form = SearchForm(request.GET)
else:
    ...
    search_form = SearchForm(initial={...})
```

Answer (score -2):

you need to specify the initial parameter when instantiating the form to get the value. Using the initial in form declaration is only for unbound form.
try:

```
search_form = SearchForm(request.GET, initial={
    'page': 1,
    'sort': 'id',
    'order': 'asc'
})
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)

Comment: That is not true, at least not as I understand the documentation. `initial=` always only works with unbound forms, regardless whether you pass it to the Form or to the Field. Passing it to the Form overrides the Field's value.